# Problems after upgrading to Flutter 2.5, Could not build the precompiled application for the device

Tags: flutter, dart, build, precompiled

I've been having problems since upgrading to flutter 2.5. I also tried flutter clean and rebooted. But it was not resolved. Ask for help!

I did a flutter run with my phone, but it didn't work.

```
> flutter run

Launching lib/main.dart on lswlsw in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: SWD9W7PNH2
Running pod install...                                              3.7s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           37.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ../../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mongol-2.2.0/lib/src/editing/text_selection/mongol_text_s
    election_controls.dart:71:10: Error: The method 'MongolTextSelectionControls.buildHandle' has fewer positional arguments
    than those of overridden method 'TextSelectionControls.buildHandle'.
      Widget buildHandle(
             ^
    ../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:123:10: Context: This is the overridden
    method ('buildHandle').
      Widget buildHandle(BuildContext context, TextSelectionHandleType type, double textLineHeight, [VoidCallback? onTap,
      double? startGlyphHeight, double? endGlyphHeight]);
             ^
    ../../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mongol-2.2.0/lib/src/editing/text_selection/mongol_text_s
    election_controls.dart:109:10: Error: The method 'MongolTextSelectionControls.getHandleAnchor' has fewer positional
    arguments than those of overridden method 'TextSelectionControls.getHandleAnchor'.
      Offset getHandleAnchor(TextSelectionHandleType type, double textLineWidth) {
             ^
    ../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:128:10: Context: This is the overridden
    method ('getHandleAnchor').
      Offset getHandleAnchor(TextSelectionHandleType type, double textLineHeight, [double? startGlyphHeight, double?
      endGlyphHeight]);
             ^
    Failed to package /Users/lsw/Desktop/FLUTTER/Geuloo/geuloo.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/lsw/Desktop/FLUTTER/Geuloo/geuloo/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in
    target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on lswlsw.
```

Flutter 2.5.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4cc385b4b8 (4 days ago) • 2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700
Engine • revision f0826da7ef
Tools • Dart 2.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this problem because of this package `mongol` You need to go to their issues section on github and file an issue report with this so that they fix their code to work with the new Flutter version.

Comment: Thank you very much. After deleting the mogol package, it works fine. Thank you!